# How to prevent FUNCTYPE from being collected

Tags: python, ctypes

I am creating CFUNCTYPE objects in my script and passing them as callbacks to c.
If I make them local they are destroyed immediately and I am getting access violaton errors
Tried to gc.disable(), it doesnt help.
Today Im making global lists and putting/removing FUNCTYPE objects when needed.
Is there better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to attach the CFUNCTYPE objects to a module or class. I've found it useful to have a Python wrapper module - in essence a separate file that keeps everything at the ctypes level in one namespace.

You could add and remove your callbacks from there as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CFUNCTYPE` as a decorator.  This modifies the callback function in the module namespace and keeps its reference:

```
CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_int)

@CALLBACK
def callback():
    return 5

my_ctypes_function(callback)
```

Versus the following which destroys the CALLBACK object when the line completes:

```
my_ctypes_function(CALLBACK(callback))
```